# Trouble setting up UltraVNC over my router

Tags: firewall, vnc, nat, windows-firewall, ultravnc

I'm trying to setup UltraVNC on my home computer so that I can access it through my router. I'm running Windows 7, with UltraVNC 1.0.8.2, over a Linksys WRT610N Router.

I'm able to connect to my computer directly by entering my own local ip (192.168.1.xxx:5900), or access the Java HTTP client with (12.168.1.xxx:5800). So I know the server is working. However I can not figure out how connect externally through my routers external IP address (24.xxx.xxx.xxx).

From what I understand VNC runs over port 5900, or 5800 if using the Java plugin over HTTP. So I've setup my Router to forward Port 5800, and 5900 to the IP of my computer. I've tried adding an outbound and inbound rule to windows firewall for winvnc.exe to allow connection over TCP for port 5900, and 5800. For the inbound rule I also allowed "edge traversal". I've also tried completely disabling the windows firewall.

However, after all this I am still not able to connect the VNC viewer back to my computer through my routers external IP (24.xxx.xxx.xxx:5900). The viewer just sits there trying to connect. The HTTP java plug-in also does not work through the 24.xxx.xxx.xxx:5800 address.

What else could be preventing me from connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and the solution was very stupid. The admin site for my router has an additional setting to disable all NAT routing at all. This was checked so my router was ignoring any of the port forwarding settings I had setup. It all worked fine once I unchecked this box.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect to the 24.xxx IP from your internal network? If yes, it will not work from your network unless you do SNAT or MASQUARADE. Try to connect to 24.xxxx from outside your network and it should work if you can connect to VNC from your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have entered the correct IP address for your home computer on the router.  [Port Forward](http://portforward.com/) has a step by step guide on configuring the [Linksys WRT610N firewall for VNC](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT610N/VNC.htm).

You can use the [GoToMyVNC](http://www.gotomyvnc.com/) service scan, to remotely test if VNC firewall rules are working.